# I am a mother. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am a mother
>
> Born in a mother
>
> Not the one that made me
>
> But in one other
>
> I swallowed myself whole
>
> Then swallowed another
>
> Continually pregnant
>
> I don’t produce an other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> One of those Russian dolls that go inside each other? These are Matryoshka dolls (thanks Lukas Rotter for the comment)

I'm working on the explanation but it's hard on phone. **Edit: Updated now that I'm on a PC.**

I am a mother
Born in a mother

> A mother inside another (and so on)

Not the one that made me
But in one other

> But not the actual person (who may be a mother) who manufactured it.

I swallowed myself whole
Then swallowed another
Continually pregnant

> A doll inside a doll inside a doll and so on.

I don’t produce an other

> Doesn't produce an other. This could either mean it doesn't produce an actual child, or it could mean that the doll only has 1 doll inside it (not including the dolls inside that doll) - it never produces 2 separate dolls inside (at the same "level").

Comment: They're called [Matryoshka dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) :)